How can I upgrade matplotlib to the current github branch (beyond the current stable release)?
I'm currently dealing with a an incredibly annoying bug in matplotlib, as described in this question. I'm a bit familiar with git, but only for small projects, and I certainly don't know anything about working with "real" git projects, like matplotlib.
Based on my reading of the bug page, this bug is fixed in #28269, which has been merged to the matplotlib main branch, but these updates have not yet been released in a stable version.
I can confirm that I'm currently rocking matplotlib 3.8.0, which is the most recent stable release, and thus pip install matplotlib -upgrade doesn't do anything for me.
This bug is utter hell for me right now, as it randomly crashes halfway through my long complex code that is batch updating a suite of plots (and after I just spent the better part of a week writing the code that produces such updates). These plots are time-critical for me, and I'm unsure what the best way to proceed is.
I'm trying to follow this question and install a specific git commit, namely the matplotlib main branch, which again evidently solves this. However, pip install git+[link] fails for a variety of links I've tried, namely https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib, https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/28425, and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/main. The last two fail because the repository is not found, and the first because git or pip appears to be having trouble finding Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe.
My question: am I going down the wrong path? What is the most expedient way to install a future version of matplotlib, even if unstable? Or is there another fix you would instead recommend?

1st, try nightly build: https://matplotlib.org/stable/install/index.html#install-a-nightly-build . If that doesn't help see https://matplotlib.org/stable/install/index.html#id1 about installing from source — that harder then just pointing to a correct URL.

@phd Awesome, thanks. I have discovered that the error appears to be more apparent when the plots are executed in rapid succession, which while bizarre, will solve my problem in the short term.

if bug needs only few lines of modification then you could open code which you already have on disk and add manually these lines. If you would keep code in venv then it can be safe for future updates. And this way you can work with project until they create official version of matplotlib. BTW: to remember about changes you could describe it (with details) in file README.md in your project
